# Xamarin Forms - How to enable ListView ViewCell.ContextActions on Xamarin.Android TabbedPage?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm having trouble enabling ViewCell.ContextActions on Android.

I have a TabbedPage where I disabled the SwipePaging option (android: TabbedPage.IsSwipePagingEnabled = "False") and within ContentPage I have a ListView where I would like to display the ContextActions MenuItens.

However in Android is not Swiping, even after trying to enable the option in ViewCell (android: ViewCell.IsContextActionsLegacyModeEnabled = "true") as described in the following article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/android/viewcell-context-actions

One more thing, I am receiving the following message:

> the attachable property 'IsContextActionsLegacyModeEnabled' was not
>   found.

On IOS everything working like a charm!

MainPage.xaml

```
<TabbedPage
   xmlns:android="clr- namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core" android:TabbedPage.IsSwipePagingEnabled="False" >
```

ListView.xaml

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core">
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell android:ViewCell.IsContextActionsLegacyModeEnabled="true">
                    <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                        <MenuItem Clicked="OnUpdate" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" Text="Update" />
                        <MenuItem Clicked="OnDelete" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" Text="Delete" IsDestructive="True" />
                    </ViewCell.ContextActions>...</ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: are you aware that iOS uses a swipe for context menus while Android uses a long press?

Comment: OMG are you right, is there any option to do something similar on both platforms?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.  Long-press is the standard behavior for context menus on Android, and users should be used to it.

Comment: There is the [SwipeView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/swipeview) which might give you the functionality you're looking for. It's still in Preview though. Microsoft has an [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/populate-data#context-menus) of using it with a collection view.